# Prove these two conditional probabilities are equivalent

Tags: probability, bayesian

I saw people using such equivalence $$P(X|\mu) P(\mu | D) = P(X,\mu|D)$$
how to prove it is valid?

My attempt:
\begin{align}
P(X|\mu) P(\mu | D) &= P(X|\mu) \frac{P(\mu,D)}{P(D)}\\
&= P(X|\mu) \frac{P(D|\mu) P(\mu)}{P(D)}\\
&=\frac{P(X,\mu) P(D|\mu)}{P(D)}
\end{align}
where $P(X,\mu|D) = \frac{P(X,\mu,D)}{P(D)}$. I have stuck here, couldn't figure out why $P(X,\mu,D) = P(X,\mu) P(D|\mu)$.

**Edited Additional:**

If instead we have $P(X|\mu,D) P(\mu | D)$, then
\begin{align}
P(X|\mu,D) P(\mu | D) = \frac{P(X,\mu,D)}{P(\mu,D)} \frac{P(\mu,D)}{P(D)}=P(X,\mu|D)
\end{align}
seems like in order to obtain such equivalence it implicitly assumes $P(X|\mu,D)=P(X|\mu)$, correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Yes, your paragraph "Edited Additional:" is spot on. The phrase for the condition at the beginning of your post is that $X$ and $D$ are independent *conditionally on $\mu$*.

Answer (score 0):

As Did points out, yes, especially for the **Edited Additional**.

$$
\begin{aligned}
P(X|μ,D)&= P(X|μ) \\[10pt]
\Leftrightarrow \frac{P(X,μ,D)}{P(μ,D)} &= \frac{P(X,\mu)}{P(\mu)} \\
\Leftrightarrow \frac{P(X,μ,D)}{P(μ)} &= \frac{P(X,\mu)}{P(\mu)} \frac{P(D,\mu)} {P(\mu)} \\
\end{aligned}
$$

which means $P(X,D|\mu) = P(X|\mu)P(D|\mu)$. It is called conditional independence of $X$ and $D$ on $\mu$.